# METAMASK NO confirmation popup (Truffle tutorial)

Tags: truffle, metamask

The first time i tried the [pet shop tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) of Truffle, it worked without problem.

**The problem:**
The second time today I don't get a metamask pop-up to confirm an adoption. It goes straight to "success". In Ganache I can see a contract call, but it says "value 0".

**I checked:**
Ganache server, port & metamask. All in order. I can even send ether from one account to the other through meta mask.

I also did `migrate --reset`.

I have no idea what the problem is. I get no console log errors.

## Ganache:

[image]

## Metamask:

[image]

## App.js:

```JavaScript

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: function() {
    // Load pets.
    $.getJSON('../pets.json', function(data) {
      var petsRow = $('#petsRow');
      var petTemplate = $('#petTemplate');

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        petTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(data[i].name);
        petTemplate.find('img').attr('src', data[i].picture);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-breed').text(data[i].breed);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-age').text(data[i].age);
        petTemplate.find('.pet-location').text(data[i].location);
        petTemplate.find('.btn-adopt').attr('data-id', data[i].id);

        petsRow.append(petTemplate.html());
      }
    });

    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    // Is there an injected web3 instance?
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    } else {
      // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('Adoption.json', function(data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with truffle-contract
      var AdoptionArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.Adoption = TruffleContract(AdoptionArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.Adoption.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      // Use our contract to retrieve and mark the adopted pets
      return App.markAdopted();
    });
    return App.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-adopt', App.handleAdopt);
  },

  markAdopted: function(adopters, account) {
    var adoptionInstance;

    App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      adoptionInstance = instance;

      return adoptionInstance.getAdopters.call();
    }).then(function(adopters) {
      for (i = 0; i < adopters.length; i++) {
        if (adopters[i] !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
          $('.panel-pet').eq(i).find('button').text('Success').attr('disabled', true);
        }
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },

  handleAdopt: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

    var adoptionInstance;
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        adoptionInstance = instance;

        // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
        return adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: account});
      }).then(function(result) {
        return App.markAdopted();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this bug for 3 days, and after trying many things I found out the method to restore your Metamask functionality without fail:

1. First of all, make sure you don't have any other node than Ganache running in the background, no private node, no other Geth.
2. Go to the directory of your truffle project and **delete the build directory** of that directory.
3. Open a fresh Ganache instance and in your terminal `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all` in your truffle project directory.
4. In your browser open Metamask, switch your network to the *Main Ethereum Network* and then switch back to your *private network* where your Ganache is running.
5. Then just to be safe completely quit and restart the browser, open your Metamask with your password, check if you are still on your private network, and everything should be fixed!